# Why is this code for font-family not working?

Tags: css, fonts

What's wrong with my code? Theoretically this should work but the font is not showing.

font is found in: `⁨themes⁩ ▸ themename ▸ ⁨fonts⁩ ▸ Cinque Donne ▸ CinqueDonne-Bold.ttf`

CSS file is found in: `⁨themes⁩ ▸ themename ▸ style.css`

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CinqueDonne-Bold';
    src: url('./fonts/Cinque Donne/CinqueDonne-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove starting "." in url because when you type ./fonts it goes to back one folder which means it goes to theme folder and finding fonts folder which not found.. and in result font family not working.
Instead of your code you can try this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CinqueDonne-Bold';
    src: url('fonts/Cinque Donne/CinqueDonne-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: 2 dots goes up a directory. 1 dot indicates the current directory.

Comment: That doesn't work. "/", "./", "../" - none of those worked